# Grouping galleries with Colorbox modules

Tags: media

Since two days that i'm looking around to find a easy and simple gallery for Drupal 7.32 and it seems much more complicated that how should be.

I think [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) is exactly what i'm looking for but I cannot find a good tutorial or resource that explain how to create a page with thumbnails that groups different galleries.

So when click on them I should go in another page and see all those thumbs from one specific gallery and be able to click on that and see them as slideshow.

More or less like here:
http://www.hopkinsco.com/portfolio

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Of course if you want to suggest another module or method is fine as well.

Comment: I achieve exactly what you want. Let me the time to explain my process in an answer ;-)

Comment: It will be awesome! Take your time :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please note we don't accept questions whose topic is "Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The content-type "gallery"**

First of all, I created a content-type "gallery" which has several fields of my choice and a field "image" with illimited number of images.

**The View**

If I don't want something too specific, I use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create a View of all my galleries. I hope you already know that module. If not, go read the [basics](https://www.drupal.org/node/1911062).

- Choose **content** of type **gallery**
- Set the title and the path of the page, etc...

You can choose which fields to show. If you want something like the site you linked in your question, you can use this configuration:

- Format: grid (with number of columns to 4)
- Fields:

  - Title
  - Image

    - Image style to thumbnail or whatever you created
    - Link to content (to land on gallery page when you click on the image)
    - Multiple value fields settings: display 1

Normally, you have now the equivalent of http://www.hopkinsco.com/portfolio when you open your View page.

**The gallery page**

The page of the content-type gallery displays all the fields you created for this content-type, in the order you arranged them in the admin. If you want something simple with the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module, you can go to admin/content-types/gallery/manage display and set the image field config like this (sorry for the french):

[image]

Then go click on the little gear on the right to set the advanced config:

[image]

Now you've got the equivalent of http://www.hopkinsco.com/portfolio/colonial.

**The template and/or the style**

Now that you've got the right content in the right place, you can customize the rendering with a little template and/or CSS.

Comment: Yeyyy!!! It works great!! :D Thank you very much, you save me a lot of headache :)

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: Is there a way I can link to a specific display of a content type (not the standard, full content display)?