# View with Colorbox triggered galleries

Tags: 7, views, javascript, media

How can I create a view that consists of images that trigger a gallery of images (grouped by node ID) in a colorbox?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can create a Views gallery that consists of images that each trigger a Colorbox gallery (with grouped images).

This can be done with a pure views approach.

Install the [Image URL Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) and create a **basic view** (filtered by the desired content type) **with the following fields**:

- Content: Nid
- Content: Images (your field with images)
- Content: Images (the same field, again)

**Configure the fields as follows:**

> **Content: Nid**
>
> - Check "Exclude from display"
>
> **Content: Images** (the first field, which will be the visible cover image)
>
> - Formatter: Image URL
> - URL type: Absolute file path
> - Multiple field settings: display "1" value(s)
> - Rewrite results: `<a href="[field_images]" class="colorbox" rel="gallery-[nid]"><img src="[field_images]" /></a>`
>
> **Content: Images** (the second field, which consists of links to the other images)
>
> - Formatter: Image URL
> - URL type: Absolute file path
> - Multiple field settings: display "all" value(s) starting from "1"
> - Rewrite results: `<a href="[field_images_1]" class="colorbox" rel="event-[nid]"></a>`

I'm sharing this because I couldn't find any reference myself ([this approach](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/grouping-galleries-with-colorbox-modules/135225#135225) didn't do it for me).